# Why would Angular try to parse {{string}} as an expression ({string})?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

Apologies if I am missing something obvious. I have looked at similar issues but this is usually down to someone using `{{...}}` where they shouldn't, but I just can't see what is wrong in this instance.

I'm trying to implement an Angular autocomplete/typeahead ([angucomplete-alt](http://ghiden.github.io/angucomplete-alt/)) but I have come across a peculiar issue. It has been implemented *exactly* as the author describes but Angular throws the following error in the console:

`Error: [$parse:syntax] Syntax Error: Token '{' invalid key at column 2 of the expression [{{placeholder}}] starting at [{placeholder}}].
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.5.3/$parse/syntax?p0=%7B&p1=invalid%20key&p2=2&p3=%7B%7Bplaceholder%7D%7D&p4=%7Bplaceholder%7D%7D
    at angular.1.5.3.min.js:68
    at Object.AST.throwError (angular.1.5.3.min.js:14006)
    at Object.AST.object (angular.1.5.3.min.js:13993)
    at Object.AST.primary (angular.1.5.3.min.js:13899)
    at Object.AST.unary (angular.1.5.3.min.js:13887)
    at Object.AST.multiplicative (angular.1.5.3.min.js:13874)
    at Object.AST.additive (angular.1.5.3.min.js:13865)
    at Object.AST.relational (angular.1.5.3.min.js:13856)
    at Object.AST.equality (angular.1.5.3.min.js:13847)
    at Object.AST.logicalAND (angular.1.5.3.min.js:13839)`

The strange thing is that the directive doesn't appear to be doing anything special. Placeholder is passed in as `placeholder: '@'` and then output in the directive template as `placeholder="{{placeholder}}"`. As far as I know that is correct.

I have declared `angucomplete-alt` as a dependency to my main app module. This is how the autocomplete is set up in my view (an exact replica of the authors first demo with `selected-object` and `local-data` changed to bind data from my controller:

```
<div ng-controller="RosterController as roster">
    <div angucomplete-alt id="ex1"
         placeholder="Search crew"
         maxlength="50"
         pause="100"
         selected-object="roster.selectedCrew"
         local-data="roster.crew"
         search-fields="name"
         title-field="name"
         minlength="1"
         input-class="form-control form-control-small"
         match-class="highlight">
    </div>
</div>
```

And this is the relevant part of my controller:

```
angular
    .module('aa.roster')
    .controller('RosterController', RosterController);

function RosterController () {
    var vm = this;
    vm.crew = [
        { name: 'abc', id: 1 },
        { name: 'def', id: 2 },
        { name: 'ghi', id: 3 }
    ];
}
```

I did try falling back to Angular 1.4.6 (the version the author uses on their demo page) but the same error persists.

What is causing Angular to try and parse `{{placeholder}}` as a single curly brace expression instead of just outputting the string?

Comment: Post the actual code, event better a JSFiddle

Comment: I can't post a JSFiddle (for some reason it won't work, even with basic Angular concepts). I'll update the question with some code although what I have is very simple.

Comment: Just an observation, but that library is rather old. The demo page [here](http://darylrowland.github.io/angucomplete/) is using: AngularJS v1.2.9

Could be something to keep in mind.

Comment: @sebastianForsberg That is angucomplete whereas my question specifically mentions (and links to) angucomplete-alt - a fork since the original is no longer maintained. I have since resolved this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have now resolved this issue. A third party module was affecting how `$templateCache` was loading templates and it was either trying to load a different template than that supplied in the angucomplete-alt module, or was affecting how the template was parsed.

Removing the third party module resolve this issue.